# configuring jquery ui dialog to replace javascript confirm

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

```
$back = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE roll_no=".$_POST['roll']) or die(mysql_error());
$backup = mysql_fetch_array($back) or die(mysql_error());
<form method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='undo' value='Undo' 
        onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to rollback deletion of 
            <?php echo $backup['name'];?> 
            from 
            <?php echo $backup['post'];?>
            ?')"/>
</form>
```

how can i replace the javascript confirm with jquery ui dialog with the above arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="submitform" method='post'> ... </form>

   $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                        .html("<div><span>Submit form " + document.getElementById('phpcode').innerHTML+"</span></div>")
                        .dialog({
                            modal: true, title: 'Submit form', zIndex: 100, autoOpen: true,
                            width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                            buttons: {
                                Yes: function () {
                                    $("#submitform").submit();
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                },
                                No: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });


<div id="phpcode"><?php echo $backup['name'];?> 
            from 
            <?php echo $backup['post'];?>
            ?')"/>
</div>
```

That should work same as simple javascript confirm dialogue.

Comment: pls read the question carefully man. i know how to use jquery ui dialog. just dont know for my specific situation. sending the arguments retrieved from the database to the modal.

Comment: useful answer but won't work for my situation. i'm using such more than 10 forms in that page by looping through the database query. for each of them, if i write such jquery code, i'll literally die. :(

Comment: what i need is, if i can call a javascript function with the arguments up on submitting which can show a jquery ui modal and can return true or false like js confirm, it would be helpful.

Comment: @RatDon Then put this in a function and pass form id through it. This will work.

Comment: for 10 forms i need to create 10 forms using the database result and div for all of them using the same values again. :(