# How do i implement a confirmation dialog/box before ajax request is send to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my admin panel I'm editing user details with Jquery/Ajax by clicking on a link. It's successfully working but I want to show confirmation dialog/popup box before request is send to server. If It's yes then my function **(myfunc1)** will be executive otherwise it will be close. My current code is look like this.

```
<td width="70"><a href="#" onClick="myfunc1('<?php echo $uid;?>') "><input type="button" value="Edit Details" class="button" /></a></td>

function myfunc1(id) {
    id = id;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit_user_details.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            //$('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
            $('#sent_password_result' + id).html(response);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
                window.location.href = "users.php";
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I do this with jquery/Javascript ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is `id = id` for?

Comment: @Barmar It's a user id. In my php code it's looping within while()

Comment: I mean why are you setting a variable to itself. That doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `confirm()`

```
function myfunc1(id) {
    if (confirm("OK to submit?")) {
        $.ajax({        
            url: 'edit_user_details.php',
            type: 'post',             
            data: {'id' : id},
            success: function(response) {
            //$('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
                $('#sent_password_result'+id).html(response);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false); 
                    window.location.href = "users.php"; 
                }, 5000 );  
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Or you can call it in the `onclick`:

```
onclick="if (confirm('OK to submit?')) { myfunc1('<?php echo $uid;?>'); } "
```

Comment: How do i call this `confirm()` function from the link ?

Comment: The link is calling `myfunc1`, and `myfunc1` calls `confirm` as I showed.

Comment: So can i use two function in `onClick` function ?

Comment: You can put as much Javascript code as you want in `onclick`.

Comment: Well, I use your code but it's not asking me to yes or not. Something I missing ?

Comment: I was missing a quote, I just fixed it.

Comment: O.Cool. it's working but is there anything which will show a ncie confirmation design box except this default confirmation ?

Comment: You can use a jQuery dialog, but it's more complicated. You need to put the code to send the AJAX in the call back of the dialog's `OK` button.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186530/configuring-jquery-ui-dialog-to-replace-javascript-confirm

Comment: Well Barmar thanks for your help. I got it. Awesome Answer from you.